# While opening a Bam file with the SeqAn library I get 'seqan::FileOpenError'

Tags: sam, reads, c++

When I try to open a simple bam file with the SeqAn library using the following code:

```
CharString bamFileInName = getAbsolutePath("/home/omair/TFG/Files/9827_2#49.bam")
BamFileIn bamFileIn(toCString(bamFileInName));
```

I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'seqan::FileOpenError'
  what():  Could not open file /home/omair/Programs/seqan//home/omair/TFG/Files/9827_2#49.bam: iostream error

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

The file exists and the path is correct.

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/302804/

Comment: Do you really have a file called `/home/omair/TFG/Files/9827_2#49.bam`? Please [edit] your question and show the exact code you are using. What you have posted has to be a copy/paste error, it makes no sense.

Comment: Duplicate of https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/cannot-open-bam-files-with-the-seqan-library

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `getAbsolutePath` call — your path is already absolute. `getAbsolutePath` garbles it, as you can see in the error message.

Comment: By removing the getAbsolutePath call I get the following error:   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'seqan::UnknownExtensionError'
  what():  Unknown file extension of /home/omair/TFG/Files/9827_2#49.bam: iostream error

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Comment: @OmairIqbal Ensure that seqan was compiled with zlib support. See [here for details](https://github.com/seqan/seqan/issues/871).